# Which OTRS actions send outgoing mail?

Tags: otrs

Is there a list which ticket actions send an email [to the customer]? For "note internal/external" it's quite obvious, but nothing tells me if "Phone Call Inbound/Outbound" notify anyone.

Is this documented somewhere? Is it possible to configure an indication at each actionwhether it's going to send something out?

Comment: You want to send email when a ticket is created or as a note to notify customers??

Comment: @SujanShrestha I want to have an indication/warning if my action is going to send an email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not. 
Only if you create a new article type that is "email" it will get send. By default you can create a new "email ticket"  and you can select an e-mail outbound or reply to an e-mail message.

by default only email-external, email-internal, email-notification-ext, email-notification-int get send. All other Times can only be seem from inside OTRS.

Comment: where do you know this from? I didn't find any user/agent documentation.

Comment: That is good question, learned it by using the application 10 years, you could join the IRC channel on oftc / #otrs